# No matching distribution found for opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv

I have python 2.7 and when I try to install opencv I get error

```
pip install opencv-python

Looking in indexes: http://pypi.dd.dynamore/simple, https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Collecting opencv-python
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

I have the latest pip version (19.2.3). And I have also installed this

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

Comment: try `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Answer (score 4):

I run into the same problem when trying to install this library for learning ML. After a little online research that points me to the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/), I believe this error is caused by a compatibility issue between python2 and this module.

Try using python3 and install this package again with `pip3 install opencv-python`

Hope this helps!

Comment: For anyone stumbling around, the `3` is the key here.  I'm brand new to Python, so thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

This error was also occurred in my case. So try using:

```py
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `python.exe -m pip install opencv-contrib-python` . It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked for me:

```
python3.8 -m pip install opencv-contrib-python
```